# Remove all Tags with inner Content

Tags: php, html

I want to Remove all Tags with inner Content.

I'm using the following function.

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

    preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
    $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

    if (is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
        if ($invert == FALSE) {
            return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:' . implode('|', $tags) . ')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
        } else {
            return preg_replace('@<(' . implode('|', $tags) . ')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
        }
    } elseif ($invert == FALSE) {
        return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

But i am still getting the following result.

```
<p><span style="color: rgb(38, 38, 38); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; fon...
```

I want all the html tags to be removed.

`p, span etc.` Where am I wrong?

Comment: where is the test string ? Can u be more clear

Comment: PHP tags? I don't see any PHP there...

Comment: <p><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12.00119972229px; letter-spacing: 0.600059986114502px; line-height: 17.2817268371582px;">The next generation Escalade and Escalade ESV. Is the arrival of the most anticipated generation of Cadillac’s crown jewel worthy merely of an introduction, or more of a celebration? </span><br></p>

This is my string. And I want to remove all html tags from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use th `PHP's` built-in function `strip_tags` .

```
$striped_string = strip_tags($your_html_string);
```

**NOTE:** You can also optionally make sure certain tags do not get stripped by passing those tags as a second parameter

Take a look at the [PHP  DOCS](https://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 150) worked for me..Thankyou everyone for your time :)

Comment: This does not remove the content inside the tags.. isn't the original question about Remove all Tags **with inner Content**?